# Redirect subdirectories using RedirectMatch and removing query string

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect a subfolder to an upper level subfolder and remove the query string

Source URL: `mysite.com/blog/folder/?start=20`

Destination URL: `mysite.com/blog/`

When I use

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/folder/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/blog/?
```

It goes to `mysite.com/blog/?`

When I use

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/folder/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/blog/
```

It goes to `mysite.com/blog/?start=20`

Is there a way to completely strip the query string including the question mark?

Answer (score 1):

try adding the following to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/folder/ [NC]
#the ?at the end will remove the querystring
RewriteRule .  http://mysite.com/blog/?  [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I up-voted this as it appears to work for me. Although I do appreciate the question was asking for a RedirectMatch method, I think it's worth highlighting this answers value